# Create Pivot table in an excel file using python

Tags: python, excel, pivot

Can anyone guide me on creating pivot table in an excel file using python? I have tried some methods. But did not work

Comment: this question is about an interesting topic but it does not meet the community standards. could you please enrich the question with some more information about your source excel sheet and which features would you like to have displyed in your pivot table? also provide information about what have you tried to do. thanks

Answer (score 1):

**can you try this:**

go to terminal install===>

```
 pip install xlsxwriter

 pip install pandas
```

**Example code:**

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import xlsxwriter

new_technologies= {
    'Courses':["Python","Java","ASP.Net","Python","C"],
    'Fees' :[22000,25000,23000,28000,26000],
    'Duration':['30days','50days','30days',  '38days', '30days']
          }

df = pd.DataFrame(new_technologies)


pivot = df.pivot_table(index =['Courses','Duration'],
                       values =['Fees'],
                       aggfunc ='sum')
print(pivot)
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('test.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
pivot.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='welcome', index=True)
writer.save()
```

**Related documentation:**

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.pivot_table.html

Comment: Okay, this is the correct answer please assign the mark